# Vue input filtering object/array

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a function in my controller that is simply hitting an API and creating an array from the objects which holds a group_code and group_name. The group_code can be treated as a key.

I've bound this to my view and I have a vue instance with an input where I'm trying to simply filter through the objects and append the selected object. Think autocomplete, except the object is already loaded and I just want to filter and select.

But nothing is showing in my results, before or after I type. I'm hoping maybe I just have a variable wrong somewhere, but what am I missing here to make my object results appear in my unordered list as I type?

Controller:

```
public function searchcategories(Request $request)
{
    $userNum = $this->user;
    $category = new categoryService();
    $safecategories = $category->info($userNum);

    $groupResult = array();

    foreach($safecategories->categories as $categories){
        $groupItem = array();
        $groupItem["group_code"] = $categories->group_code;
        $groupItem["group_name"] = $categories->group_name;

        array_push($groupResult, $groupItem);
    }

     return view('campaigns')
        ->with('groupResult', $groupResult);

}
```

Blade

```
<div id="categoryNames">
<input type="text" v-model="keywords">
<ul v-if="results.length > 0">
  <li v-for="result in results" :key="result.group_code" v-text="result.group_name"></li>
</ul>
</div>

var categoryNames = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      keywords: null,
      results: []
    };
  },

  computed: {
    filteredResults () {
      return this.keywords ? this.results.filter(row => row.name.search(new RegExp(`${this.keywords}`, 'i')) !== -1) : this.results
    }
  }
}).$mount('#categoryNames');
```

Comment: Can you share the codes: - `results` is updating with API response, - `filteredResults` is using?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand, but currently both of those arrays are empty in the vue console. It should be getting an array from groupResults like 'group_code:123' 'group_name: 'Group One'

Comment: Sanity check. Do you have the javascript inside a script tag?

Comment: Yes I do, sorry didn't add it but it's in a working javascript section